# BDDMockito `given(...).willReturn(...)` calls the mock just once instead of each call to the `given()` function

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I have a static method defined into an utility class which executes shells commands on a Unix environment:

```
public final class Shell {
    
    public static String execute(String[] commands, long timeout) {
        //do stuff
    }

}
```

This method is used to perform Bash commands on the environment, which means we don't only have a `String` in return containing the output for a specific command, but also some effects of the command itself may take place.

For example, in a specific case, the command generates an `.out` file and returns the status of the operation as a `String`.

For testing purposes, I need this call to be mocked. Hence, I need it to generate the `.out` file as a mock and return something.
To do that, I used `BDDMockito` and `PowerMockito` as follows:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Shell.class);
BDDMockito.given(Shell.execute(eq(specificArgument), anyLong()).willReturn(mock_out_execution());
```

... where `mock_out_execution()` is a function that creates the `.out` file on the working directory, then returns a successful state - simulating the execution on the real Unix environment.

> Background info: the `.out` file is treated by a process that reads it, does something and then deletes it. This information is important to understand my problem.

Now, during the execution of my integration test,

- The `execute()` method of `Shell` is called a first time. An `.out` file is created.
- The `.out` file is consequently treated and deleted by the main thread
- The `execute()` method of `Shell` is called a second time. An `.out` file is supposed to be created again.
- The `.out` file should consequently be treated again and deleted once done.

The problem is that `BDDMockito.given(...).willReturn(...)` only executes once, when the mock is initialized.
This means that the first time `execute()` is called, the `.out` file is there and the process can treat it.
However, the second time `execute()` is called, nothing is executed again and so the new `.out` file is missing and the execution of the code fails.

How can I go around this problem? What would be the correct way of using `PowerMockito` to actually call the mock every time the method I want to mock is called?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `willReturn` you pass a constant object, which will be computed immediateöy. If you want to return somthing dynamic, which is calculated *at the moment of the call* for each call separately, you have to use `willAnswer()`.

The answer object you pass is basically a function to convert the invocation (all data about the call is in this object) to the concrete result per call.

---

Edit:

Tried this, works fine. Maybe this helps when comparing notes:

```
// Mocked service
package stuff;

public class StaticService {
   public static String fetchStuff() {
      return "Stuff";
   }
}


// Test class
package stuff;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.BDDMockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(fullyQualifiedNames = "stuff.StaticService")
public class PowerMockitoTest {
   @Test
   public void testStatic() {
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticService.class);
      AtomicInteger cnt = new AtomicInteger(0);
      BDDMockito.given(StaticService.fetchStuff()).willAnswer(invocation -> Integer.toString(cnt.getAndIncrement()));
      System.out.println(StaticService.fetchStuff());
      System.out.println(StaticService.fetchStuff());
   }
}
```

Result

```
0
1
```

Comment: I have replaced `.willReturn(mock_out_execution())` with `.willAnswer((Answer<String>) invocation -> mock_out_execution())`;. However, if I debug the test, the method `mock_out_execution()` is never called whereas with `.willReturn()` is called once at mock initialization. Am I wrong with the syntax?